# Invoke base class function as derived

Tags: c++, c++11

Is there any way to call base class method from virtual function as derived class, not as base one?
Example code:

```
class A
{
public:
    virtual void a() = 0;
    void print() { std::cerr << typeid(decltype(*this)).name(); };
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    virtual void a() { print(); }
};

int main() 
{
    B b;
    b.a(); //prints 1A, I want it to print 1B, is it even possible?
}
```

Comment: By overriding `print` in `B`.

Comment: `print` is not virtual...

Comment: @SHR Making it virtual doesn't help, you need an actual override: See http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b2c336a564ff315e

Comment: @SHR this is not the real reason... The underlying reason is that you use decltype which is a static type deduction... use `typeid(*this).name()` and the program will work as expected.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just drop the `decltype`:

```
void print() { std::cerr << typeid(*this).name(); };
```

`this` always points to an instance of the class whose member function its in. `this` inside `A` is always an `A*`. So `typeid(decltype(*this))` always gives you `A`.

On the other hand, `typeid(*this)` will lookup runtime type information, which will determine that `this` is really a `B` (because `A` is a polymorphic type).